COMO valido un campo Integer en una petición POST de apirest SPRING BOOT?
No puedo validar si mi campo es integer, porque si envío una a o "a", o un numero muy largo que se excede de integer, se me cae la solicitud.
Por ejemplo, si envio en mi campo "idRol":  "a", a, 3284798344, , null, true :
    {
        "id": 1,
        "idRol": a,
        "nombreCli": "Juan",
        "apellidoCli": "Pérez",
        "correoCli": "hola@example.com",
        "claveCli": "clave123",
        "rutCli": "20.980.760-2",
        "celularCli": "+56912345678",
        "direccionCli": "Calle 123, Santiago"
    }

me tira este error desde POSTMAN:
"message": "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'a': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')",
    "path": "/api/v1/clientes/crear"
}
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",

Quisiera que me valide que es integer, a continuación muestro mi código:
Mi archivo de "clienteController":
@PostMapping("/crear")
    public ResponseEntityDTO saveCliente(@Valid @RequestBody ClienteDTO clienteDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        try {
            if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return new ResponseEntityDTO("hola", "400");
            }else{
                ResponseEntityDTO cliente = clienteService.saveCliente(clienteDTO);
                return cliente;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return new ResponseEntityDTO("Se ha producido un error al intentar crear el cliente, intente mas tarde"+ex, "400");
        }
    }

Mi archivo de "clienteService":
    public ResponseEntityDTO saveCliente(ClienteDTO clienteDTO) {
        //Validaciones campos nulos están en clienteDTO.

        if(clienteDTO == null){
            return new ResponseEntityDTO("El cliente no puede ser nulo", "400");
        }

        if(clienteDTO.getIdRol() == null) {
            return new ResponseEntityDTO("El cliente no puede ser nulo", "400");
        }else{
            if (clienteDTO.getIdRol() != 2){
                try{
                    Integer.parseInt(clienteDTO.getIdRol().toString());
                }catch(Exception e){
                    return new ResponseEntityDTO("El cliente desde el service"+e, "400");

                }
            }
        }


mi archivo de "clienteDTO":
//representa un objeto de transferencia de datos
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ClienteDTO {
    //@NotNull (este si validar que no sean letras)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message="idRol no debe ser nulo")
    @Min(value = 1, message ="el valor debe ser 1" )
    private Integer idRol;


Y MI ENTIDAD CLIENTE:
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @ColumnDefault("nextval('cliente_id_cli_seq'")
    @Column(name = "id_cli", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message="idRol no debe ser nulo")
    @Min(value = 1, message ="el valor debe ser de una longitud min 1" )
    @Max(value = 1, message = "el valor debe ser de una longitud max 1")
    private Integer id;

    @ColumnDefault("2")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_rol", nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message="idRol no debe ser nulo")
    @Min(value = 1, message ="el valor debe ser de una longitud min 1" )
    @Max(value = 1, message = "el valor debe ser de una longitud max 1")
    @NotEmpty(message = "no vacio")
    private Integer idRol;


Necesito que mi api no se caiga ante estas solicitudes.

El hecho de que se "te caiga" la llamada debería darte la pista:
Has declarado el valor como integer en tu clase, por lo que Spring (Jackson, realmente) va a intentar tomar el valor y guardarlo como Integer. Como el JSON enviado es inválido (ano es un número y para ser un texto debería ir entre comillas dobles), obtienes un HTTP 400 Bad Request (Petición incorrecta). Es decir, no pasa la validación y Spring devuelve el error correspondiente
